# jQuery AJAX POST requests get stuck in pending state

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi have a bit of an odd situation where AJAX POST requests get stuck in a pending state after being fired and never execute.  This ONLY happens on my work machine.  I actually initially thought it was an issue with the app I'm developing, but even trying to submit this question took me ages because the POST request to submit the data wouldn't fire.

On the ASP.NET MVC application the AJAX request was being fired but the controller was never being hit. What could cause the POST requests to be stuck in a pending state?

[image]

Comment: I tried to edit the post to say that after a few attempts submitting the question work, but when trying to save my edits the POST request got stuck...

Comment: Well since it happens on sites other than the one you are coding it sounds like a internet connection problem, and hence falls under general hardware/software which are off-topic here

Comment: Have you tried testing these `POST` requests from various browsers? If it only happens on one browser brand it could be a browser-specific problem (updated browser plugin behaving weirdly and so on)